# Checking that String has a valid number

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, unsigned-long-long-int

I'm a programming newbie and I'm currently writing a conversion calc program in objective c and I'm really struggling.

I have a string representing a unsigned long long value. I need a way either when attempting to add another character to check that the new character would not go above LONG_LONG_MAX  before adding it. Or deleting the last character if the value is/would be above LONG_LONG_MAX

the only possible way I could think to even try this is:

```
- (BOOL) isNumberStringValid:(NSString *)stringValue {
      unsigned long long uVal = strtoull(stringValue.UTF8String, NULL, 0);

      if (uVal <= ULLONG_MAX) return TRUE;
      else return FALSE;
}
```

I know this doesn't work because uVal would always be <= ULLONG_MAX but I can't think of any other ways to possibly check. Can anyone help me find a way to accomplish this???

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that `strtoull()` sets the value of `errno` to `ERANGE` if the given
string was out of range:

```
- (BOOL) isNumberStringValid:(NSString *)stringValue {
    errno = 0;
    unsigned long long uVal = strtoull(stringValue.UTF8String, NULL, 0);
    return (errno == 0);
}
```

Some test (ULLONG_MAX = 2<sup>64</sup>-1 = 18446744073709551615):

```
1234 : TRUE
18446744073709551615 : TRUE
18446744073709551616 : FALSE
1844674407370955161678 : FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNumberFormatter.  Unfortunately NSNumberFormatter stores the 'maximum' value as a float, so there are some problems around the boundary of LONG_LONG_MAX.  To deal with that this code checks for nil or a long long value that is negative (which means that it overflowed)

```
-(BOOL) isNumberStringValid:(NSString *)stringValue
{

    [NSNumberFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    NSNumberFormatter *f=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];

    NSNumber *max=[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:LONG_LONG_MAX];

    [f setMaximum:max];

    BOOL valid=NO;

    NSNumber *num=[f numberFromString:stringValue];
    if (num != nil)       // A nil value means that input was > LONG_LONG_MAX
    {
       long long x=[num unsignedLongLongValue];  // A negative value here means that the input was > LONG_LONG_MAX
       if (x>0)
       {
        valid=YES;        
       }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: There was a typo in the `[f setMaximum]` line - corrected

Comment: You can also subclass that or create a custom formatter.

Answer (score -1):

the if statement you have is checking if uVal is less than or equal to LONG_LONG_MAX

```
unsigned long long uVal = (unsigned)stringValue.longLongValue;
if (uVal >= LONG_LONG_MAX) {
    return YES;
}
else {
    return NO;
}
```

I ran this and it works fine.

Comment: Your logic seems to be reversed - you return yes if the number is too big and no if it isn't - the function should return YES if the number is valid, but it also doesn't work because of the overflow when you assign a number greater than LONG_LONG_MAX to uVAL.  Try it with your string equal to "9223372036854775809" - you end up with a 4294967295

Comment: OK this code does seem to work for me:'code' NSString *string = @"9223372036854775807";
    unsigned long long uVal = strtoull(string.UTF8String, NULL, 0);
    NSLog(@"%llu", uVal);
    if (uVal >= LONG_LONG_MAX) {
        NSLog(@"no");
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"yes");
        return YES;
    }